# Как получить несколько строк из строкового ресурса (windows phone 8.1)?

Tags: c#, строки, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, ресурсы

В файле ресурсов есть строковый ресурс **somestring** со значением вида **"первая строка \n вторая строка"**.
Есть TextBlock, в который должны выводиться эти строки, соответственно с переносом строки. Но они выводятся почему-то в таком виде, как написаны, т.е. "\n" просто пропечатывается и строки не переносятся.
Я пробовал ресурс и привязывать в xaml через **x:Uid**, и в коде через **ResourceLoader**, результат один и тот же и не тот, что нужен.
Как можно решить это проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте \r\n вместо \n

Comment: Попробуйте вместо использования символа '\n' в строке ресурса нажать `Shift` + `Enter`.

Comment: Ну да, с Shift + Enter получилось, но как-то это извращённо :)

Comment: @Vlad: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @denny7794: Ну, ``\`` имеет специальное значение только в исходниках на C#, что поделать?

Comment: @VladD, сейчас оформлю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо `\n` нужно использовать `Shift` + `Enter`. Текст в ресурсах не форматируется escape-последовательностями.